# postgresql archive permission denied

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

We have installed postgres v12 on ubuntu 20.04 (with `apt install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib`) and wish to enable archiving to `/data/db/postgres/archive` by setting the following in `postgresql.conf`:

```
max_wal_senders=2
wal_keep_segments=256
wal_sender_timeout=60s
archive_mode=on
archive_command=cp %p /data/db/postgres/archive/%f
```

However the postgres service fails to write there:

```
2022-11-15 15:02:26.212 CET [392860] FATAL:  archive command failed with exit code 126
2022-11-15 15:02:26.212 CET [392860] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: archive_command=cp pg_wal/000000010000000000000002 /data/db/postgres/archive/000000010000000000000002
2022-11-15 15:02:26.213 CET [392605] LOG:  archiver process (PID 392860) exited with exit code 1
sh: 1: pg_wal/000000010000000000000002: Permission denied
```

This directory `/data/db/postgres/archive/` is owned by the `postgres` user and when we `su postgres` we are able to create and delete files without a problem.

Why can the postgresql service (running as postgres) not write to a directory it owns?

Here are the permissions on all the parents of the archive directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 postgres root 6 Nov 15 14:59 /data/db/postgres/archive
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 21 Nov 15 14:29 /data/db/postgres
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 22 Nov 15 14:29 /data/db
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 44 Nov 15 14:29 /data
```

Comment: is SELINUX enabled?

Comment: From the error message, the permission problem is related to the source file in `pg_wal`, which should be impossible, unless somebody or something messed with the data directory. What are the permissions on that WAL segment?

Comment: That is not a legal syntax for the postgresql.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2022-11-15 15:02:26.212 CET [392860] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: archive_command=cp pg_wal/000000010000000000000002 /data/db/postgres/archive/000000010000000000000002

So, your archive_command is apparently set to the peculiar string `archive_command=cp %p /data/db/postgres/archive/%f`.

After the %variables are substituted, the result is passed to the shell.  The shell does what it was told, which is to set the (unused) environment variable 'archive_command' to be 'cp', and then tries to execute the file pg_wal/000000010000000000000002, which is not allowed to because it doesn't have the execute bit set.

I don't know how you managed to get such a deformed archive_command, but it didn't come from anything you showed us.

Comment: That's a very oblique way of telling me I garbled the config!  But you're right of course - I posted the correct setting but actually I had `archive_command = 'archive_command=cp %p /data/db/postgres/archive/%f'` ‍♂️